# Manually scroll to a child in a Gtk.ScrolledWindow

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtkscrolledwindow

I'm developping a GTK app (in Python with PyGTK) and I need to scroll manually the Gtk.ScrolledWindow to a child it contains to show it in the screen.

The ScrolledWindow contains a ListBox, which contains a lot of ListBoxRow.

`self.currencySwitcher = CurrencySwitcher(self)
self.currencySwitcherBox = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(vexpand = True)
self.currencySwitcherBox.add(self.currencySwitcher)`

CurrencySwitcher herits of Gtk.ListBox:

`class CurrencySwitcher (Gtk.ListBox):
    # ...`

I have a search system to find a specific row in this ListBox, but when I click by searching on a row, it is not visible on the screen (I must scroll to see it)
So I must be able to scroll to a child to see it on the screen without have to manually scroll the ScrolledWindow

How can I do this ? I have already search a lot but i can't found a good answer.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we can see what you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Gtk.ListBox` also inherits from `Gtk::Container`, so have a look at the `set_focus_vadjustment()` and `set_focus_hadjustment()` members of `Gtk.Container`.

Once you have called one or both of these functions on your ListBox, you can have your ListBoxRow child `grab_focus()` (inherited from Gtk.Widget) and it will be scrolled into view.